# Pop window does not closes after calling hide also in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-material

This is my function

```
(function(){
             'use strict';
       function TablePopUpController($http, prod, tableName, $mdDialog, $scope,$timeout,$location) {
             $scope.tableName=tableName;
             var datas=[];
             //$location.reload();
             $scope.submitData = function() {
                    if (tableName == 'WFSmartPriority') {
                           var url = prod.TrfUrl + "/GetWFSmartPriority?tableName="
                                        + tableName + "&OrgID=" + $scope.OrgID+"&"+prod.TrfApiKey+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
                           $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
                                 datas=data.GetWFSmartPriorityResult;
                           //     console.log(datas);


                                 hideData(datas);// Calling function to hide pop ip 


                           });

                    } else {
                           if($scope.market==undefined)
                                 $scope.market=' ';
                           if($scope.OrgID==undefined)
                                 $scope.OrgID=0;
                           if($scope.userGroupID==undefined)
                                 $scope.userGroupID=0;
                           var url = prod.TrfUrl
                                        + "/GetWFMarketOrgUserGroup?tableName=" + tableName
                                        + "&OrgID=" + $scope.OrgID + "&Market="
                                        + $scope.market + "&UserGroupID="
                                        + $scope.userGroupID+"&"+prod.TrfApiKey+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
                           $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
                                 datas=data.GetWFMarketOrgUserGroupResult;
                                 console.log(datas);
                                 hideData(datas);
                           });
                    }

             }


             function hideData(data){
                    //$mdDialog.cancel(data);
$mdDialog.hide(data);
                    console.log('after hide');


             }

       }
             angular.module('celeritas').controller(
             'TablePopUpController',['$http', 'prod', 'tableName', '$mdDialog', '$scope','$timeout','$location',TablePopUpController]
             )
})();
```

After ajax success i am calling   `$mdDialog.hide(data);` but then also it does not closes the pop up window .

When i refresh and do something it closes second time .
I dont know what am i missing .

I debugged also all looks fine.I get data value also but pop window it does closes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution you gave and its working fine there might be some other reason for the dialog not getting closed.

```js
angular.module('dialogDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $http) {
 $scope.showAlert = function(ev) {
  $mdDialog.show({
   controller: DialogController,
   templateUrl: 'dialog.tmpl.html',
   parent: angular.element(document.body),
   targetEvent: ev,
   fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
  });
 };
  
  
 function hideData(data){
  $mdDialog.hide();
  console.log('after hide');
 }

 function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.hide = function() {
   $mdDialog.hide();
  };

  $scope.submitData = function(answer) {
   var url = "https://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/jsonp/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&data={%22foo%22:%22aaa%22}";
   console.log(answer);
   $http.jsonp(url).success(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    hideData(json);// Calling function to hide pop ip 
   });
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="dialogDemo1">
  <head>
    <link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="md-padding" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak>
    <div class="dialog-demo-content" layout="row" layout-wrap layout-margin layout-align="center">
   <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAlert($event)"   >
    Alert Dialog
   </md-button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="dialog.tmpl.html">
   <md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)">
    <form ng-cloak>
     <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
       <h2>Mango (Fruit)</h2>
       <span flex></span>
       <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
        <md-icon aria-label="Close dialog">Click me</md-icon>
       </md-button>
      </div>
     </md-toolbar>

     <md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-dialog-content">
       <h2>Using .md-dialog-content class that sets the padding as the spec</h2>
       <p>
        The mango is a juicy stone fruit belonging to the genus Mangifera, consisting of numerous tropical fruiting trees, cultivated mostly for edible fruit. The majority of these species are found in nature as wild mangoes. They all belong to the flowering plant family Anacardiaceae. The mango is native to South and Southeast Asia, from where it has been distributed worldwide to become one of the most cultivated fruits in the tropics.
       </p>
       <p>
        The highest concentration of Mangifera genus is in the western part of Malesia (Sumatra, Java and Borneo) and in Burma and India. While other Mangifera species (e.g. horse mango, M. foetida) are also grown on a more localized basis, Mangifera indica&mdash;the "common mango" or "Indian mango"&mdash;is the only mango tree commonly cultivated in many tropical and subtropical regions.
       </p>
       <p>
        It originated in Indian subcontinent (present day India and Pakistan) and Burma. It is the national fruit of India, Pakistan, and the Philippines, and the national tree of Bangladesh. In several cultures, its fruit and leaves are ritually used as floral decorations at weddings, public celebrations, and religious ceremonies.
       </p>
      </div>
     </md-dialog-content>

     <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <md-button ng-click="submitData('not useful')">
       Not Useful
      </md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="submitData('useful')">
       Useful
      </md-button>
     </md-dialog-actions>
    </form>
   </md-dialog>
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as i have already shown its working with your partial code. If its not working then you can share the whole code using the URL i have used for making ajax request.